# How to delete files in tmpfs or /tmp directory for Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-functions

I have a google cloud function I've written in Node.js which I have set to execute every 4 hours using the cloud scheduler. Basically the function populates a table I have in BigQuery. My function doesn't explicitly write anything to the tmp directory, it just stores things in local variables for streaming insertion into BigQuery like so:

```
var rows = []

// code which fills the rows array

await bigqueryClient
      .dataset(datasetId)
      .table(tableId)
      .insert(rows)
```

I've noticed (looking at the graph of memory usage) that the memory used with each invocation goes up until it reaches the limit set for the function (I have 512MB for this one), and then I get an error logged - "Error: memory limit exceeded. Function invocation was interrupted."

I've tried the below code to try to remove all files in the tmp directory, but it seems like there are no files to delete:

```
const directory = '/tmp';

fs.readdir(directory, (err, files) => {
  if (err) throw err
  console.log(files)

  for (const file of files) {
    fs.unlink(path.join(directory, file), err => {
      if (err) throw err
    })
  }
})
```

What gets logged is just an empty array '[ ]'.

What am I missing here? Is the problem something else?

Comment: I'm curious why are you expecting anything to be in /tmp if you didn't put something there.  Also, if your function is only executing every 4 hours, it's basically impossible for the state from a previous run to be retained for the next run.  Cloud Functions won't keep an idle server instance alive that long.  If you're running out of memory, that's almost certainly happening due to what's happening in a single run.

Comment: Well that's the thing, I didn't expect anything to be in /tmp, but then looking at the graph over time it looks like something is retained because there is a pattern where each invocation takes up more memory than the last until failure, then it looks like it 'resets' the folder. Here is a screenshot of the standard patten of the memory usage https://i.imgur.com/zbolNHG.png

My function should technically take similar memory with each invocation, so this pattern is not expected.

Comment: The memory usage just looks kinda random to me over time.  I don't see an established pattern.  I suspect you're worried about nothing.

Comment: Thanks for the responses. Perhaps my memory usage issue is unrelated to the /tmp folder contents altogether, and maybe to do with my function. 

That being said, what is the best practice for deleting files in the tmpfs or /tmp directory? The best practices page says to always delete temporary files - https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips - but there isn't any strict guidance on doing so. 

Is my approach using fs.unlink() sufficient? What is best practice?

Comment: Perhaps [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51480118/deleting-files-in-tmp-folder-of-google-cloud-functions?rq=1) that @DougStevenson answered another time may shed some light on the temporary files for Cloud functions.

Comment: Also, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44653533/cleanup-temp-directory-firebase-cloud-functions?rq=1) could be interesting for you. It seems you may delete a whole directory using 'fs.rmdir()'

Answer (score 0):

Your code will delete all files the **next** time it runs, but if you created a file with something like `const ws = fs.createWriteStream('/tmp/${fileName}');`, the file will not be deleted until the next run.

If you want to delete all files as part of the current process, then you can separate the part that creates a file(s) from the file cleanup and wrap both in a `Promise`.

This will delete all files in `/tmp`.

```
const directory = '/tmp';
const fileName  = `test_file_1.gz`;
 
function doSomething() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {   
    const ws = fs.createWriteStream(`/tmp/${fileName}`);
    resolve();
  });
}

function fileCleanup() {
  return new Promise((resolve) => {   
    fs.readdir(directory, (err, files) => {
      if (err) throw err;
      console.log(files);

      for (const file of files) {
        fs.unlink(path.join(directory, file), err => {
          if (err) throw err;
          console.log(`${file} was deleted`);
        });
      }
    });
    resolve();
  });
}

doSomething().then(() => { fileCleanup(); }).then(() => { res.status(200).send('OK'); }).catch((err) => { throw new Error(err); });
```

Remove `res.status(200).send('OK');` if it is not an HTTP trigger.  Also, for local testing, I create a directory called tmp.  The Cloud Function uses `/tmp` but locally it is `./tmp`.